# Можно ли вызвать функцию, изменив некоторые ее параметры (ее содержимое)?

Tags: javascript

Есть некоторая большая функция вначале файла. В ней происходят взаимодействия с переменной **number**. Мне нужно вызвать ее повторно, но так, чтобы в ней изменилась **только** переменная **number**, а в остальном она осталась такой же.

```
let number;
let number1 = 3;
let number2 = 15;

function test1() {
    number = number1;
    //а далее производятся махинации с переменной number
}

test1() {
    number = number2;
}
//возможно ли как-то это реализовать, чтоб функция работала как прежде, но с измененной 
переменной?
```

Comment: `function test(num) { number = num; }; test(number1); test(number2);`

Answer (score 1):

То о чём вы просите называется объектно ориентированное программирование. ООП - это когда результат вычисления функции зависит не только от её параметров но и от штуки под названием объект. Функция тогда называется методом объекта:

```js
class Increment {
    constructor () {
        this.increment_ = 0;
    }
    setIncrement(increment) {
        this.increment_ = increment;
    }
    increment(value) {
        return value + this.increment_;
    }
}

const i = new Increment;

const inc = value => i.increment(value);

console.log(inc(1));
i.setIncrement(1);
console.log(inc(1));
i.setIncrement(2);
console.log(inc(1));
```

В этом примере объект хранит состояние общее для двух функций. То же самое можно сделать без объявления класса. Замыкание будет играть роль объекта:

```js
const makeIncrement = () => {
    let increment = 0;
    return [
        increment_ => {
            increment = increment_;
        },
        value => value + increment
    ];
};

const [setIncrement, inc] = makeIncrement();

console.log(inc(1));
setIncrement(1);
console.log(inc(1));
setIncrement(2);
console.log(inc(1));
```